# angularjs ng-click inside google maps infowindow doesn't fire

Tags: angularjs

How do I fire the event inside infowindow.
I have a button inside google maps infowindow using ng-click.
When I click it, nothing alert and error.
Any idea?

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 240,
    content: "<button ng-click=\"test()\">Click me</button>"
});
```

Test function.

```
$scope.test = function() {
   alert('This is infowindow');
}
```

Comment: I found it. It is call bind.  I will try and see if it work

Answer (score 7):

To make `ng-click` event trigger, info window content needs to be compiled using `$compile` service.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('map-example', [])
    .controller('MapController', function($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {


        function initialize() {

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: { lat: -38.363, lng: 131.044 }
            });



            $scope.cities = [
                { title: 'Sydney', lat: -33.873033, lng: 151.231397 },
                { title: 'Melbourne', lat: -37.812228, lng: 144.968355 }
            ];


            $scope.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
            });


            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.cities[i].lat, $scope.cities[i].lng),
                    map: $scope.map,
                    title: $scope.cities[i].title
                });

                var content = '<a ng-click="cityDetail(' + i + ')" class="btn btn-default">View details</a>';
                var compiledContent = $compile(content)($scope)

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, scope) {
                    return function() {
                        scope.infowindow.setContent(content);
                        scope.infowindow.open(scope.map, marker);
                    };
                })(marker, compiledContent[0], $scope));

            }

        }

        $scope.cityDetail = function(index) {
            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.cities[index]));
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    });
```

```css
 html, body {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.1/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div ng-app="map-example" ng-controller="MapController"> 
    <div id="map"></div>   
</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RNyB3r5PMMpNgoxUZgX3?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/EbBWJQx5pOz0UyoayYFI?p=preview

fixed by waiting on the "domready" of the infowindow and compiling then

Comment: I think the key to your fix is using document.getElementById to lookup the content which has already been added to the DOM. I was stuck in a similar situation, I could get binding to work, but not ng-click/ng-include until I stopped passing the content in a variable and started using looking up the DOM element.